# How to reducing this code as a one-liner

Tags: excel, vba

Does anyone know how to take a piece of code and reduce it to the shortest possible form?
My current code is as follows

> Sub shide_Click()
>
> ```
>   Columns("a").Hidden = Not Columns("a").Hidden
>   Columns("e").Hidden = Not Columns("e").Hidden
>   Columns("g").Hidden = Not Columns("g").Hidden
>   Columns("s").Hidden = Not Columns("s").Hidden
>   Columns("y").Hidden = Not Columns("y").Hidden
> ```
>
> End Sub

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider:

```
Sub Shorter()
    For Each l In Array("a", "e", "g", "s", "y")
        Columns(l).Hidden = Not Columns(l).Hidden
    Next l
End Sub
```